# Why my Ajax request doesn't work in Safari on IOS?

Tags: iphone, ajax, jquery

I have an ajax jsonp request done with JQuery that is done in the $(document).ready. It works perfectly fine in all browsers and even in Chrome on IOS but it doesn't always work in Safari on IOS. Sometimes, the code never return to success nor complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this today and spent a lot of time to fix it. Finally, what solved the issue was to move the javascript code at the end of the page instead of in the document.ready. This seem to be a bug with Safari.

I thought I'd share in case anyone else runs into this!

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off "Private" browsing in Safari.